# Access shared vagrant-folder from windows-box on windows-host without 'net use'

Tags: windows, batch-file, vagrant, virtualbox

From the virtual machine (Windows Server 2016 Core), i cannot access the shared folder **C:\Vagrant** ( Symlink to \vboxsrv\vagrant, default for VirtualBox-provider of vagrant ), without first attaching it as a network-drive.
I don't even have to access it via the network-drive, attaching it is enough...

Console from the virtual machine that show's the behavior:

```
C:\>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows 2016
 Volume Serial Number is 9814-DDEB

 Directory of C:\

04/05/2018  02:09 PM    <DIR>          inetpub
04/05/2018  01:33 PM    <DIR>          Logs
07/16/2016  01:18 PM    <DIR>          PerfLogs
04/05/2018  02:18 PM    <DIR>          Program Files
04/05/2018  02:17 PM    <DIR>          Program Files (x86)
04/05/2018  02:07 PM    <DIR>          Scripts
07/24/2018  08:21 AM    <DIR>          Users
07/24/2018  08:20 AM    <SYMLINKD>     vagrant [\\vboxsrv\vagrant]
07/24/2018  08:21 AM    <DIR>          Windows
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               9 Dir(s)  30,747,582,464 bytes free

C:\>cd Vagrant
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\>cd vagrant
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\>net use X: \\vboxsrv\vagrant
The command completed successfully.


C:\>cd vagrant

C:\vagrant>    LOL  <------------------------
```

The vagrant-file looks like this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "ajourtestserver"
    config.vm.box_url = "file:///u:/TestImage/ajourtestserver.json"
    config.vm.box_check_update = true
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.memory = 4096
        vb.cpus = 4
    end 
end
```

Can anyone explain what is going on? This seems very weird to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never found an explanation, but adding the "net use" statement as inline shell provisioning seems to be a reliable workaround. For anyone else having this problem, here is some details on my workaround.

The following was added to VagrantFile:

```
config.vm.provision "symlink-fix", type: "shell" do |s|
    s.inline = "net use X: \\vboxsrv\vagrant"
end
```

The statement actually fails:

```
==> default: Running provisioner: symlink-fix (shell)...
    default: Running: inline PowerShell script
==> default: System error 67 has occurred.
==> default: The network name cannot be found.
```

... So no 'X:' network drive is added - but the C:\Vagrant folder can now be accessed ¯\_(ツ)_/¯